# Grappled by more than one creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple

How would you rule a situation where creature is being held in place (grappled) by more than one creature.  For example, 2 prison guards holding a prisoner still for a beating?

If the held character tries to break free, do they roll separately to break each grapple?  Can they try to break free from both on the same turn?