# Multiple Giant Spider web

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, stacking

When fighting against multiple of the Giant Spider creature and more than one manage to web you, do you need to break free from each web separately, or does just one successful escape check break you free from all webs?

Comment: Related: [Can multiple attackers grapple a single target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59979/can-multiple-creatures-grapple-a-single-target#:~:text=A%20creature%20can%20be%20grappled,escape%20attempt%20against%20each%20one.&text=A%20grappled%20creature's%20speed%20becomes,any%20bonus%20to%20its%20speed.)

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): "[What happens when identical overlapping effects have their end-condition met?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169347)"

Comment: I'm gonna agree with @Medix2 This seems like a duplicate. Voting to close.

Comment: Voting to leave open here. The general question there is answered with essentially, "it depends on the feature", so it is a bit less than helpful at addressing particular features.

Comment: @Thom I see what you're saying. The problem, in my eyes, is that this answer isn't likely to receive an answer that adds any new information to the answers on that other question. This is, effectively, another example that could be included in the question of that answer. This answer asks about a different ability than the ones in that question, though, so I'm really torn on whether to vote to close this one.

Comment: Iff people are saying that Markov's answer is correct then I'm OK with closing. Is it correct though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You need multiple checks to escape.

This is a byproduct of the ["Combining Game Effects"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CombiningGameEffects) rule:

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items. See the related rule in the “Combining Magical Effects” section of chapter 10 in the Player’s Handbook.

Because of this rule, we can only be affected by a single web at a time, so we can only make a check against one web at a time. Once the effect of one web ends, we are immediately subject to the effect of the second web, as their durations no longer overlap, so a second check is necessary.

Comment: Unlike the Web spell, the Spider's inherent web ability is not an area effect so I'm not sure how it works re it.