# What is the combined movement speed of multiple grapplers moving a single grappled creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple

So specifically, there are two or three Bullywugs that are going to grab a gnome and then drag him around 200 feet away from where he currently is.  Assuming the Bullywugs successfully grapple and then maintain the grapple, what is their movement speed while dragging the creature?  I know the PHB says:

> Moving a Grappled Creature: When you move, you can drag or carry the Grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.
> But it doesn't really discuss if there are multiple grapplers.  What is the RAW in such a scenario?  If there is no RAW, how would you rule it?

Comment: I removed the first half of the title question, it has been answered in this Q&A: [Can multiple creatures grapple a single target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59979)

Comment: And I've closed this as a duplicate, I believe the linked question about movement with multiple grapplers should cover your question here.

Comment: Quick summary of the linked answer as related to this question: only the grappled target will be moved.   Others also grappling the target will no longer be grappling the target once it is moved out of range.